# Xcode hook up with Unity

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, facebook, unity-game-engine

Hi i am new bee in Unity but i have 1 year experience in Xcode, I am doing an app in Unity for iPhone but getting bit confuse on how can i hook-up Xcode with Unity, I want to Facebook sharing, Twitter Sharing and also iOS native Email sharing(Using Mail Composer) in Unity but i don't get any help ful solution to do task in Unity, I only get Plugins which i need to Purchase first. So i want to do this task in Xcode it reduce and time and money and rest of work on Unity so is this possible that we can Communicate between Xcode and Unity? If Possible then kindly share some knowledge and links with me so that i can do this task ASAP.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start write your own plugin to complete the communication between Unity3D and iOS.

From iOS to Unity, You can just use UnitySendMessage, which is enough in most of time. You can also try to use a event and delegate in Unity Script to handle more complex situation.

From Unity to iOS, you need to implement plugin yourself. First of all, use a .cs file to declare the external method. And then implement the native code in a .mm file in Xcode and "extern C" them to the Unity. Then you can call the .cs method and get a native function called. You need a Unity Pro license to use the plugin feature.

For UnitySendMessage and Unity plugin, visit [Unity Doc-Building Plugins for iOS](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html). You can find an example in the doc called Bonjour Browser Sample. It is a very good starting point for you. If you have 1 year experience with Xcode, I think it will be easy for you.

For use delegate and event in Unity, visit [Prime31's Unity Tip video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N2zdwKIsXJs).

Comment: Thanks, its already done with the help of Doc-Building Plugins for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Niklas's free unity iOS plugin.

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/122681-Free-facebook-Plugin-for-Unity-iOS

It doesn't work out of the box anymore, but with a few changes and updates you can get it working.

If you already have xCode experience then hopefully the extra work should be trivial since the Facebook SDK docs are pretty good.